# Dos and Don'ts of \countdef\mycount=<number> and \newcount vs \newcounter{} in LaTeX

Tags: macros, counters, package-writing

Let's clarify that `countdef\mycount=<number>` is a bad idea in LaTeX, then clarify appropriate usage of `\newcount\mycount` vs `\newcounter{mycount}` in LaTeX.

Background: I only started with TeX last year and before long I got tired of doing everything from scratch. Everyone surely knows what it's like reading The TeXBook. At any one time I had the book at my fingertips with around 10 or so cardboard bookmarks interspersed, jumping from bookmark to bookmark, referring to the index, adding more bookmarks, driving myself towards some solution or other.

I discovered `countdef\mycount=<reg number>` on page 119, where Knuth just tells you how to use them without any warning. So, as a naive rookie I used them, my solution worked and I had no reason to look further. Sometime later, working in LaTeX, I dredged this out of my memory and got in to trouble using it. I discovered `\newcounter{mycount}` and didn't look back.

Now that I'm looking into matters more deeply I need to raise the issue again. Back during my initial struggle to understand Plain-TeX, if I'd continued to read on to page 121, where Knuth explains the importance of `\newcount`, I wouldn't have been asking the first part of my question now. The TeXBook is a vast and complicated book and I think raising this question is a useful awareness raiser of one of the "traps for young players" in delving into Plain-TeX.

Hopefully this explains how I originally fell foul of such a fundamental error and I'm pointing out that others could do the same. Also, as there are many times when using Plain-TeX in creating a LaTeX solution is useful, I'd really like to know the dos and don'ts of `\newcount` vs `\newcounter{}` in LaTeX.

Comment: You should use `\newcount\mycount`. Or even better `\newcounter{mycount}` which creates a counter with name `\c@mycount`.

Comment: Doing `\countdef\mycount=81` is a really bad idea also in Plain TeX.

Comment: @tohecz I have a little picky remark (hope that you don't get it wrong): the counter is still called 'mycount'. `\c@mycount` is the internal count register.

Comment: @tohecz I said in the OP that I discovered `\newcounter{}` already. My question is about illuminating the whys and wherefores.

Comment: @Ruben So, what are the dos and don'ts of the capital letter when talking about Plain TeX? Many people write Plain-TeX when referring to the layer that Knuth wrote over the top of the TeX primitives. That is what I'm referring to here.

Comment: @GeoffPointer The edit was more about dash in 'Plain-TeX'. The lowercasing may was a little to radical, as far as it can be found very often. But consider the following source: "This is the *plain TeX* format that's described in The TeXbook..." (from `plain.tex`, line 1) [emph. mine].

Comment: I've edited the question into something more reasonable, which still matches the answer and leaves room for a little more discussion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a bad idea to do

```
\countdef\mycount=81
```

in *all* flavors of TeX. No discussion allowed.

Plain TeX allocates 25 count registers; it can be checked from any `tex.log` (or `plain.log`) on your machine. So, if a macro package says

```
\newcount\foo
```

TeX will execute internally `\countdef\foo=26`, but the actual number should *never* be used. So, assume you load `eplain` and some other macro package; they'll allocate new counters and, maybe, they'll use 56 of them. When you do `\countdef\mycount=81`, any subsequent assignment to `\mycount` will clobber the value the macro package is assuming the counter holds. Or a macro call will clobber the value *you* are counting on.

Do `\newcount\mycount` (which works also in LaTeX, although it should be used carefully and only in package code) and no such problem will arise.

For your information, the last counter allocated by LaTeX is number 78. Other eleven are allocated by `amsmath`. Do you see the problem? Counter 81 (if `amsmath` is the first package called) would be `\classnum@`, which is a very important internal register for `amsmath`. Chaos ensues.

---

Let's tackle the ‘*`\newcount` versus `\newcounter`*’ question. The former is a Plain TeX construct also imported by LaTeX, while the latter is LaTeX specific. With `\newcounter{foo}[baz]` one creates a LaTeX counter `foo` that's added to the *reset list* of the counter `baz`; an example is

```
\newcounter{section}[chapter]
```

that's done by the `book` class. Adding the ‘parent’ counter is optional. After a `\newcounter{foo}` declaration (with or without an optional argument), LaTeX defines

1. `\c@foo` via `\newcount\c@foo`
2. `\thefoo` via `\newcommand\thefoo{\arabic{foo}}`

and also `\p@foo` (but describing this would be too technical).

We can use the commands `\arabic{foo}`, `\alph{foo}`, `\Alph{foo}`, `\roman{foo}`, `\Roman{foo}` and `\fnsymbol{foo}` for getting a representation of the counter's current value. Most importantly, we can use

```
\stepcounter{foo}
\addtocounter{foo}{<number>}
\setcounter{foo}{<number>}

\refstepcounter{foo}
```

to change the current value. I typed the last command in evidence because it not only steps the counter, but also (locally) defines `\current@label` so that the next `\label` command will reference this value (more precisely, the current representation of the value).

In order to behave well with the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, *all* the above operations on the counter (using the allocated register named `\c@foo`) are ***global***.

In the majority of documents, there's no need to do arithmetic with registers involving multiplications and divisions, so no `\multiplycounter` and `\dividecounter` macros are defined at the user's level.

In case a package needs to do arithmetic, TeX counters directly defined with `\newcount` are available for doing local or global computations with the primitives `\advance`, `\multiply` and `\divide`. Several packages use TeX counters (I use this name as opposed to ‘LaTeX counter’ for those described above).

Because of the inherent global nature of LaTeX counters, it's bad practice operating on them with `\multiply` or `\divide`: operations on a register should be always local or always global. So `\global\multiply\c@foo by 2` should be used in case one *really* needs to, which is quite rare, in my experience.

Comment: What you say is what I assumed. I'm making sure that I miss no other aspects of the issue. I originally got the `\coundef\mycount=81` from The TeXBook. Coming from a history of writing C++ I was never comfortable with it. You distinguish between `.tex` and `.sty` usage of `\newcount\mycount`. Are you saying it is best to use that in a package or would you care to elaborate? This is what my question is aiming at. Best practice. Cheers

Comment: I've rewritten the question and your answer still fits it. What I would like if you wouldn't mind is for you to top up your answer with some expansion on your comment about usage of `\newcount'. Thanks for your help so far, it has pushed me to read further into Knuth's book and I'm starting to enjoy it. Cheers

Comment: @GeoffPointer I added something about “TeX versus LaTeX counters”.

Comment: In using the word register - do you mean the one that is implicitly behind `\newcounter{num}`? Could you expand on why you say "operations on a register should be always local or always global"? Do you mean with `\newcount\num`, operating on `\num` locally only affects `\num` locally and sometimes that's useful, whereas `\newcounter{num}` doesn't have that choice? I get your point about `\divide` and `\mutiply`, I guess if you have a situation where they're useful, don't use `\newcounter{num}` in that case, because its main abstraction idea is as a counter not an integer in general.

Comment: @GeoffPointer `\newcount` should be issued at the outermost level. This has no influence on what `\advance` and so on do to the register; the point is that LaTeX implicitly uses `\global\advance` when operating on its counters (defined with `\newcounter`).

Comment: So, you're saying a LaTeX counter is not appropriate if I want to do some local manipulations? There are times when you do want a global value updated from a local context. Should I not be doing that with a TeX counter?

Comment: @GeoffPointer For local manipulations you don't need `\refstepcounter` (which is the main reason for all operations being global), so a TeX counter is probably preferable.

Comment: This conversation is a bit abstract without some examples. Are there some good concrete examples you could refer me to that highlight what you're trying to explain?