# \newcounter vs \newcount

Tags: numbering, tex-core, counters

What are the differences between `\newcounter` vs `\newcount`?

So far as my knowledge goes `\newcounter` is from LaTeX and  `\newcount` is from TeX. Also, I [find that](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) `\newcounter` has an optional automatic reset mechanism. So, if I define `\newcounter{mycounter}[section]`, `mycounter` is reset to zero every time the `section` counter is incremented.

Are there any other differences between the two? Are there specific places or situations of their use? And internally, what exactly is used by `\newcounter`? Is it actually `\newcount`?

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot. Actually [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142714/14103) answered many issues I was actually looking for.

Comment: Should we close this one as duplicate?

Comment: @egreg Since I got my answer, there is no harm closing this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of `\newcounter` is

```
\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname c@#1\endcsname{\@definecounter{#1}}
\@ifnextchar[{\@newctr{#1}}{}
```

where `\@definecounter` is

```
\expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
\setcounter{#1}\z@
\global\expandafter\let\csname cl@#1\endcsname\@empty
\addtoreset{#1}{@ckpt}
\global\expandafter\let\csname p@#1\endcsname\@empty
\expandafter\gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

So, yes, `\newcounter` does use `\newcount` internally. It also sets the new counter to zero (using the shorthand `\z@`) and defines a `\the...` command, which prints the counter as an arabic number, and, as you mentioned, has an optional reset mechanism.

Since `\newcounter` uses `\newcount` internally, the latter can be replaced with the former. The LaTeX command `\newcounter{counter}` declares a TeX count called `\c@counter`, which can be used in the usual TeX way.

Comment: The codes are fine. But I would appreciate providing other inputs. More insights, if possible. Also, you seem to have addressed only the last point in the third paragraph of my question.

Comment: @MMA: ChrisS does answer a majority of your questions. It's obvious that `\newcounter` does more than just `\newcount`. If you don't use any of the additional counters (macros) that are defined when using `\newcounter` (like `\p@<cntr>` and `\cl@<cntr>` and `\the<cntr>`), then of course you can use `\newcount`.